# Spring security formlogin and httpbasic

Tags: spring, security

I am trying to learn spring security. For just dummy service, I made 3 endpoints :

```
/secured - should be authenticated
/unsecured - authenticated not required
/test - random api
```

Now as per I learned on the web, I added the custom config like :

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/secured").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/unsecured").permitAll()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }
}
```

from what I experimented, when I did this

- /secured api is getting secured
- /unsecured api is getting unauthenticated access
- /test is getting unauthenticated access

my confusion is that below 2 lines are registering the matchers :

```
.antMatchers("/secured").authenticated()
.antMatchers("/unsecured").permitAll()
```

but what is the use of

```
.formLogin()
.and()
.httpBasic();
```

Comment: Hi Members, dont bother
This is solved now Thanks ! :) 

with some hit and try I understood what exactly is the case

Comment: Hi Amit, if you found a solution to your problem, you're always more than welcome to share it as a separate answer to your own question. It might benefit someone in the future :)